# C# using a while loop to calculate whats left on a card after purchases have been made

Tags: c#

For the code below, I'm trying to figure out to break out of the `while` loop when the card reaches `0`, and then report to the user what they owe. Right now it displays both ending messages and then reports the negative numbers when it goes over and then ends as it should. Can anyone give me a tip on what I'm doing wrong so I can move forward?

```
Console.WriteLine("how much do you have on your gift card?");
string cardString = Console.ReadLine();
decimal cardAmount;// we dont need to initalize the sum of this variable because we will get that from the user.
while (!decimal.TryParse(cardString, out cardAmount))//validate
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter how much you have on your gift card!");
    cardString = Console.ReadLine();
}
while (cardAmount >= 0) // while loop to determine amount after each purchase. 
{
    Console.WriteLine("how much was your purchase?");
    string purchaseString = Console.ReadLine();
    decimal purchaseAmount;
    while (!decimal.TryParse(purchaseString, out purchaseAmount))// validating user response inside while loop.
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter how much your purchase was!");
        purchaseString = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    cardAmount -= purchaseAmount; // this line is very important! this is how we subtract and get the values we want every time the loop goes through.
    Console.WriteLine("With your current purchase of $" + purchaseAmount + ", you can still spend $" + cardAmount + ".");

    if (cardAmount <= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("With your last purchase of $" + purchaseAmount + ", you have used your gift card up and still owe $" + cardAmount + ".");
        //break;
    }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. The code, as is, doesn't compile.

Comment: What is the desired result and what is happening? If you want it to break off at 0 or less then your condition should be cardAmount > 0

Comment: **[Debugging your code using the powerful, free, built-in (!) Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("With your current purchase of $" + purchaseAmount + ", you can still spend $" + cardAmount + ".");` should be inside an `else`.

Comment: Thank you mjwills!

Comment: @mjwills: I suggest you post your answer as an answer; [user10941846]--once posted as an answer, please accept the answer so that mhwills gets a reputation bump.

Comment: @Jazimov I have voted to close - it is basically a typo, and thus not worth reputation in my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. See comments that describe changes (`mjwills` called out the most necessary change)

**CODE**

```
using System;

namespace SO_console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("how much do you have on your gift card?");
            string cardString = Console.ReadLine();
            decimal cardAmount;// we dont need to initalize the sum of this variable because we will get that from the user.
            while (!decimal.TryParse(cardString, out cardAmount))//validate
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter how much you have on your gift card!");
                cardString = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            // MODIFIED: changed >= 0 to > 0
            while (cardAmount > 0) //while loop to determine amount after each purchase. 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("how much was your purchase?");
                string purchaseString = Console.ReadLine();
                decimal purchaseAmount;
                while (!decimal.TryParse(purchaseString, out purchaseAmount))// validating user response inside while loop.
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter how much your purchase was!");
                    purchaseString = Console.ReadLine();
                }

                cardAmount -= purchaseAmount; // this line is very important! this is how we subtract and get the values we want every time the loop goes through.

                if (cardAmount <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("With your last purchase of $" + purchaseAmount + ", you have used your gift card up and still owe $" + cardAmount + ".");
                    break;
                }
                //Added else clause
                else
                {
                    //MOVED: moved this line of code to else claue
                    Console.WriteLine("With your current purchase of $" + purchaseAmount + ", you can still spend $" + cardAmount + ".");
                }
            }

            //ADDED: added these line so use can see see last prompt written before program ends
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end program");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes after mjwills pointed out the else clause I was able to get it too work. I thought I could just leave it out but it made a huge difference in the end.

Comment: @user10941846  You're welcome. Please accept answer? Correcting the while clause is also significant.

Comment: Got it, sorry about that!